# How to extract specific file from partially downloaded tar?

Tags: ubuntu, tar, gzip

I have a large `tar` file but it could not be downloaded completely as the browser crashed when verifying the download. Is it possible to extract some files from this tar?

I am able to view the files using `tar -tf abc.tar` and this shows the directories and folders

```
a/
a/b/
a/b/1
a/b/2
```

However if I use `tar -zxvf abc.tar a/b/1` it gives

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open abc.tar
```

Is there any way to only extract the available files in the `tar` in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The archive isn’t compressed, so you need to drop the `-z` flag:

```
tar -xvf abc.tar a/b/1
```

However

> Failed to open abc.tar

suggests that the tarball itself is no longer there.